# Why i'm getting exception: Too many automatic redirections were attempted on webclient?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the top of form1 i did:

```
WebClient Client;
```

Then in the constructor:

```
Client = new WebClient();
Client.DownloadFileCompleted += Client_DownloadFileCompleted;
Client.DownloadProgressChanged += Client_DownloadProgressChanged;
```

Then i have this method i'm calling every minute:

```
private void fileDownloadRadar()
        {
            if (Client.IsBusy == true)
            {
                Client.CancelAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                Client.DownloadProgressChanged += Client_DownloadProgressChanged;
                Client.DownloadFileAsync(myUri, combinedTemp);
            }
        }
```

Every minutes it's downloading an image from a website same image each time.
It was all working for more then 24 hours no problems untill now throwing this exception in the download completed event:

```
private void Client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                span = new TimeSpan(0, (int)numericUpDown1.Value, 0);
                label21.Text = span.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
                timer3.Start();
            }
            else if (!e.Cancelled)
            {
                label19.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                label19.Text = "חיבור האינטרנט והאתר תקינים";
                label19.Visible = true;
                timer3.Stop();
                if (timer1.Enabled != true)
                {
                    if (BeginDownload == true)
                    {
                        timer1.Start();
                    }
                }                
                bool fileok = Bad_File_Testing(combinedTemp);
                if (fileok == true)
                {
                    File1 = new Bitmap(combinedTemp);
                    bool compared = ComparingImages(File1);
                    if (compared == false)
                    {

                        DirectoryInfo dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(sf);
                        FileInfo[] fi = dir1.GetFiles("*.gif");
                        last_file = fi[fi.Length - 1].FullName;
                        string lastFileNumber = last_file.Substring(82, 6);
                        int lastNumber = int.Parse(lastFileNumber);
                        lastNumber++;
                        string newFileName = string.Format("radar{0:D6}.gif", lastNumber);
                        identicalFilesComparison = File_Utility.File_Comparison(combinedTemp, last_file);
                        if (identicalFilesComparison == false)
                        {
                            string newfile = Path.Combine(sf, newFileName);
                            File.Copy(combinedTemp, newfile);
                            LastFileIsEmpty();
                        }
                    }
                    if (checkBox2.Checked)
                    {
                        simdownloads.SimulateDownloadRadar();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    File.Delete(combinedTemp);
                }
                File1.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Now it stopped inside the if(e.Error != null)
On the line: timer1.Stop();

Then i see on the Error the error:
This is the stack trace:

```
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
```

How can i solve this problem so it won't happen again ? And why it happened ?

EDIT:

I tried to change the fileDownloadRadar method to this to release the client every time:

```
private void fileDownloadRadar()
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                if (client.IsBusy == true)
                {
                    client.CancelAsync();
                }
                else
                {

                    client.DownloadFileAsync(myUri, combinedTemp);

                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is that in the constructor i'm using Client and here it's client two different Webclient variables.

How can i solve this and the exception ?

This is the websitel ink for the site with the image i'm downloading every minute. 
Still not sure yet why i got this exception after it was working no problems for more then 24 hours.
Now i ran the program again over again and it's working but i wonder if i will get this exception again tommorow or sometimes in the next hours.

[The site with image i'm downloading](http://www.ims.gov.il/IMS/tazpiot/RainRadar.htm)

Comment: Updated my question. I'm trying to use Using with the Webclient but not sure this is the solution for the exception. And second problem is how to use Using since now i have two different WebClient variables and that's wrong.

Comment: The error you describe has nothing to do with `using`. If you want to use a single `WebClient` instance at class level, you shouldn't have a `using` statement in your download method. Did you even read my answer?

Answer (score 31):

I had the same problem with WebClient and found the solution here:
http://blog.developers.ba/fixing-issue-httpclient-many-automatic-redirections-attempted/

Using HttpWebRequest and setting a CookieContainer solved the problem, for example:

```
HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(linkUrl);
try
{
    webReq.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    webReq.Method = "GET";
    using (WebResponse response = webReq.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            res = reader.ReadToEnd();
            ...
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're getting an exception with a description that says there are too many redirections, it's because the Web site you're trying to access is redirecting to another site, which is directing to another, and another, etc. beyond the default redirections limit.

So, for example, you try to get an image from site A. Site A redirects you to site B. Site B redirects you to site C, etc.

`WebClient` is configured to follow redirections up to some default limit. Since `WebClient` is based on [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx), it's likely that it is using the default value for [MaximumAutomaticRedirections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.maximumautomaticredirections(v=vs.110).aspx), which is 50.

Most likely, either there is a bug on the server and it's redirecting in a tight loop, or they got tired of you hitting the server for the same file once per minute and they're *purposely* redirecting you in a circle.

The only way to determine what's really happening is to change your program so that it doesn't automatically follow redirections. That way, you can examine the redirection URL returned by the Web site and determine what's really going on. If you want to do that, you'll need to use `HttpWebRequest` rather than `WebClient`.

Or, you could use something like [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) with verbose logging turned on. That will show you what what the server is returning when you make a request.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is an old topic, I couldn't help but notice that the poster was using WebClient which uses no UserAgent when making the request.  Many sites will reject or redirect clients that don't have a proper UserAgent string.

Consider setting the `WebClient.Headers["User-Agent"]`

Comment: Setting the user agent was what worked for me actually. Thanks for remember that.

Answer (score 3):

Problem can be solved by setting a cookie container and most importantly by setting `webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;` like this:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
```

Comment: Can you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278333/php-curl-to-net-httprequest-files-uploading-to-server

Answer (score 0):

I had this error but got a simple fix.

You don't need all that code, all you need is to do is in the beginning of your application download the cookie like this (sorry but i work with VB :) but is pretty simple to convert)

```
[your application namespace].Application.GetCookie(New Uri("https://[site]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to create `CookieAwareWebClient` and override the creation of the `WebRequest`.
It looks like that:

```
 public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient {
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }
    public Uri Uri { get; set; }

    public CookieAwareWebClient()
      : this(new CookieContainer()) {
    }

    public CookieAwareWebClient(CookieContainer cookies) {
      this.CookieContainer = cookies;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address) {
      var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
      if (request is HttpWebRequest) {
        (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = this.CookieContainer;
      }

      var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)request;
      httpRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
      httpRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
      httpRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 100;
      httpRequest.ContinueTimeout = 5 * 60 * 1000;
      httpRequest.Timeout = 5 * 60 * 1000;
      return httpRequest;
    }

    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request) {
      var response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
      var setCookieHeader = response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];

      //if (setCookieHeader != null)
      //{
      //    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(); //create cookie
      //    cookie.Value = setCookieHeader;
      //    this.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
      //}
      return response;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the VB.Net version of @Ron.Eng's answer:

```
Public Function DownloadFileWithCookieContainerWebRequest(URL As String, FileName As String)

    Dim webReq As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL)
    Try

        webReq.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
        webReq.Method = "GET"
        Using response As WebResponse = webReq.GetResponse()
            Using Stream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
                Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Stream)
                Dim res As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
                File.WriteAllText(FileName, res)
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try

End Function
```